# How to structure the backend of a multiplayer game

Tags: node.js, socket.io, 2d-games

I intend to create a simple mobile question-and-answer game, and some doubts have arisen about the server-side architecture of the game.

As the game will be multiplayer, I intend to use NodeJs and Socket.io, creating rooms for players to play together.

But, how to store the state of each match in each of the rooms?

I thought about saving all the information in a NoSQL database, but I don't know if it's a good idea.

Another idea I had was to use another language that supports multiple threads, creating one thread for each game started and storing the information in variables in the thread. But it also didn't seem like a good idea.

How can I do this? I am a beginner in the field of game development.

Answer (score 1):

Storing things is a database's job, so yes.  If your game will have few players you might look for an in-memory database.  NoSQL is fine since I doubt you'll be trying to query like "select all players across all current games named Roy" since each instance of a party's game would be pretty isolated from other people's.

Your tech stack is fine.

Threads are rare and are for doing work, not sitting still holding data.